# How can I make withLatestFrom() work with itself?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have **intermediate** stream which bound to **source** but also can fire events from other sources (like user input). At some other place of my program I have **derived** stream which needs to compare new impulse from **intermediate** with the last value of **source**, so it all comes down to such code:

```js
const source = new Rx.Subject;
const derived = new Rx.Subject;
derived.subscribe( () => console.log( "derived" ) );
const intermediate = new Rx.Subject;

//motivation of having "intermediate" is that sometimes it fires on it's own:
source.subscribe( intermediate );

intermediate
    .withLatestFrom( source )
    .subscribe( derived );

source.next();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.3/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that **"derived"** message is never printed (first event in **source** is ignored). How can I make some stream that for every message from **intermediate** stream gets the last value of **source** even if it's currently the propagation of **source**?

Comment: Can you make eg. marble diagram what you expect?

Comment: I would also like to better understand what you are trying to see but my gut feeling says `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: see if emit from source will work
not tested, but it fits your logic
intermediate.subscribe(source);

intermediate
    .withLatestFrom(source)
    .subscribe( derived );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a `source` stream, then an `intermediate` stream which subscribes to and emits *all* of `source`'s items and mixes in some others from user input. Then you have two differing requests, which I'll offer suggestions for separately:

**Emitting values of `source` with timings from `intermediate`:** [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) will do the job easily:

```
const source_when_intermediate : Observable<TSource> = intermediate.combineLatest(source, (i, s) => s);
```

**Comparing the latest value from `intermediate` with `source`:** While this sounds very similar, `combineLatest` isn't very safe, because if you do something simple like:

```
const is_different : Observable<bool> = intermediate.combineLatest(source, (i, s) => i !== s);
```

`intermediate` might not emit a given value from `source` before `source` emits a new one, and you could think that that stale value is unique to `intermediate`.

Instead, for maximum safety, you'll need to buffer and use a subject:

```
// untested
const derived : Observable<TSource> = (function() {
  const source_buffer = new Queue();
  const subj = new Subject();
  source.forEach(s => {
    source_buffer.enqueue(s);
  });
  intermediate.forEach(i => {
    subj.onNext(source_queue.peek() === i);
    if(source_buffer.peek() === i) source_buffer.dequeue();
  });
  Promise.all([
    source.toPromise(),
    intermediate.toPromise()
  ]).then(() => subj.onClose());
  return subj.asObservable();
})();
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for you work to make an answer. But do you also agree that such approach is really way too complicated? In this specific approach it's better not to use Rx.JS at all. Specifically, after two weeks of investigation I found out that such problem is a case of more general "diamond problem", which is solved in FRP JS libraries like flyd and bacon.js. Code is principally the same as in my question but it will just work.

Comment: @Slav This seems like a rather specific use case, so I find it a bit surprising other FRP libraries will do what you want correctly right out of the box while RxJS won't. What are you using now?

Comment: I tried to use flyd, but it didn't allowed to glue existing streams together preserving "atomic updates", but in my current project streams are created in different modules - too much work to rewrite everything with the proper operators order, so I my own tiny streams with basically **with()** and **combine()** iterators.